# firefox's inspect element show's A form inside Another Form

Tags: c#, webforms

While scraping web page i found that there was a form inside another form now that is not possible so what is wrong with that, How do i find out the correct HTML of a page because after scraping i have to render it.

And why is this form inside another form when i right click and "inspect element" in Firefox.
The inner form's font color is a bit fade, does that mean something that i don't understand...

When Scraping i should know that which form to submit with which form attributes.In this case there is some confusion.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page where you observed this behavior...?

Comment: <form action="Some URL hERE"  name="Dsp" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input>some inputs here..</input

<form action="Some URL hERE" method="POST"></form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

Comment: I have given the html that i found after inspecting the element in firefox.

Comment: Can you just let me see the page with a link or paste? If I can't view the source, how would I be able to tell you if it was generated, errantly coded in the page, or other?